# SQL "ContainsAll" query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have recipes table and ingredients table and table that connect ingredients to the recipes.

I have a list of ingredients, how to write a SELECT statement (or store procedure) that will return a recipes that have ALL given ingredients?

How to write this query for MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I finally have a solution. :)

```
SELECT *
FROM recipeTable r JOIN ingredintsTable i ON r.RecId= i.RecId
WHERE i.IngredientId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING ( COUNT(r.id) > 1 )
```

Comment: I works great, that's why I chose this one. I wonder which one is more efficient? Mine or Quassnoi's one?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    repice r
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    ingredients i
        WHERE   i.recipe_id = r.id
                AND i.ingredient_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
        )
```

The `OFFSET` parameter should equal to `n - 1`, where `n` is the number of ingredients in the list.

This assumes that `(recipe_id, ingredient_id)` combination is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared 'd' in the HAVING clause. I assume you meant to put 'r' in there.